# Unbuffered CXF (No content-length header)

Tags: stream, jaxb, jersey, cxf, flush

I recently switched from using Jersey to CXF for a JAX-RS application.  I was also using StreamingOutput to output my own stream, as the data contained in the stream takes ~20s to create, and can be partially processed by clients.  This was all working fine with Jersey, but I've now switched to returning JAXB beans with CXF and can't get the streaming behaviour.  With Jersey, I had to set `jersey.config.contentLength.buffer.server` to `0` and flush the `OutputStream` to get the data to the client, but I can't find the equivalent with CXF.  I've tried writing an `Interceptor` based on the `StreamInterceptor` example, but the `write` method of the `Message`'s `OutputStream` doesn't get called until all processing has finished.  The JAXB bean contains a `Collection` with a custom `Iterator` that supplies data when it's available.  I can see the data getting buffered in the debugger.

How can I stream JAXB beans with CXF?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do it with Jackson and my own MessageBodyWriter, BeanSerializerModifier, and JsonSerializer.  I still need to find a way with XML.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

/**
 * Created by jayen on 17/12/13.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"DefaultFileTemplate"})
@Produces({"application/json", "application/*+json"})
@Provider
public class ResponseJSONWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Response> {
    @Override public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Response.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Response response, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                        MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Response response, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                        MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
            mapper.setSerializerFactory(
                    mapper.getSerializerFactory().withSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
                        @Override
                        public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                                  JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                            return new FlushingSerializer<>(serializer);
                        }
                    }));
            mapper.writeValue(entityStream, response);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class FlushingSerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> {
        private final JsonSerializer<T> serializer;

        public FlushingSerializer(JsonSerializer<T> serializer) {
            this.serializer = serializer;
        }

        @Override public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            serializer.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
            jgen.flush();
        }
    }
}
```